# Rack::Deflater works if only added to config.ru

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gzip, jruby, rack

Why am I getting `Error: incorrect header check` when I add

```
class Application < Rails::Application
   config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
...
```

...but not when I add `use Rack::Deflater` to `config.ru`? I double checked: gzip works and compresses responses.

---

- Rails 3.2.15
- jRuby 1.7.13

Comment: any details on the server used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of jRuby 1.7

https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/571

And it was fixed in 1.7.23, so I just had to upgrade.